# How to send data from Spark to my Angular8 project

Tags: mysql, angular, scala, apache-spark

Technologies I am using to fetch data from my MySQL database is Spark 2.4.4 and Scala. I want to display that data in my Angular8 project. Any help on how to do it? I could not find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: What kind of data you have in mysql and how big it is in size ?

Comment: @tarun Size is around 84MB having 7 Lakh rows

Comment: you can collect the data from spark after getting from Mysql  using collect ,this returns a scala/java collection.Which you can show on gui.Checkout https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html and https://supergloo.com/spark-scala/apache-spark-examples-of-actions/   Alittle warning tought if your data is bigger in size collect will cause performance degradation.

Comment: I've already collected the entire data from MySQL using collect, I cannot find anything related to showing that data on the GUI, from the link you've shared

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a scala/spark related question. It sounds more towards system design of your project.

- One solution is to use your Angular8 directly read from MySQL. There are tons of tutorials online.
- Another solution is to use your spark/scala to read data and dump to CSV/JSON file at somewhere and use Angular8 to read in that file. The pros is that you can do some transformation before displaying your data. The cons is that there is latency between transformation and displaying. After reading the flat file into JSON it's up to you how to render that data on user's screen.

Comment: Thank you, for now I am trying with the way you've suggested by dumping the data into CSV file but considering the latency issue it would be not feasible to use this method for my live project.